# Unity 3D editor window filled with pink color

Tags: intel-graphics, unity3d

I have installed Unity 3D in my Ubuntu 18. But editor windows are filled with pink color. Only options like *file*, *Accessories* are visible.

In top of the Unity window OpenGL 4.2 is shown. So I checked my OpenGL version and it is 3.0. Mesa version is 18.x something. I followed many tutorials and ppa given online to update my driver and OpenGL. But still OpenGL version is 3.0.

I'm using Intel Atom Baytrail Z3735f Device.

Comment: So How can i Upgrade OpenGL version?

Comment: I just download it from Unity Hub or Download version 2019.2.0b10 it's works fine with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 with Intel Core i3 3320M, Intel HD 4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We Can Use Other Version of OpenGL using    -force-glcoreXY terminal command (XY is OpenGL version). 
               Using OpenGL 3.2 Solved my issue by running -force-glcore32

```
                        OR
```

Using Vulkan instead of OpenGL is a solution (-force-vulkan).

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/bt8a0r/is_there_any_way_to_force_unity_to_use_vulkan/

Comment: Thanks! `-force-glcore32` helped against pink screen on old mesa in Tabletop Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Have same problem with Intel HD 4000 and OpenGL 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.6 trying to run Unity3D 2019.3.0a2 and 2019.2.0b2 under Debian.

Found the problem on Unity3D forum: https://forum.unity.com/threads/everything-pink-in-unity-2019-1-0f2-linux-editor-except-menu-bar.663277/

Intel HD 4000 specific issue and they won't fix it (there is quote from support in the post). Based on posts, works with Unity3D 2018.X but not 2019.X . Also should work under Windows.

Unity3D 2018.4.0f1 is markes as LTS (Long Term Support) so I would need to stick with it until I get newer machine (and recommend you to do the same).
Working with integrated graphics is not good (especially with one which does not support 4K like mine).

Comment: Using Vulkan is the Solution.

Comment: or using another version of OpenGL using -force-glcoreXY and XY is OpenGL version . in my case OpenGL 3.2 worked for me